# Qt: Issue getting the settings ini file from application/executable directory

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, application-settings, qsettings

I am using Qt5.7 on Windows7.
In my current app, I have my own settings manager class, that looks like this:

**Header:**

```
class SettingsManager
{
public:
    void     write(const QString & key, const QVariant & variant);
    QVariant read (const QString & key) const;

private:
    static QSettings settings;
};
```

**Source cpp:**

```
QSettings SettingsManager::settings("settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

void SettingsManager::write(const QString & key, const QVariant & variant)
{
    settings.setValue(key, variant);
}

QVariant SettingsManager::read(const QString & key) const
{
    return settings.value(key);
}
```

My problem is: I gave the app to some friends and probably they launched it with different working directory or something, and the app didn't find the `settings.ini` file, hence it didn't work as it should...

So, the question is: How can I modify the code above to be able to get the `settings.ini` file from the application/executable directory? Obviously, The `settings.ini` file is always in the same folder as the app itself.

Comment: You don't seem to be using an absolute path.

Comment: I tried something like `( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/settings.ini" )` , but it didn't work. It said something like: _Please instantiate the QApplication object first_...

Comment: You should have a `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` in your main somewhere. You have to create the object first before calling the static functions. You have to create one anyway so it should be no big deal.

Comment: There is one object right in `main`...

Comment: You're attempting to use the settings system before `main` starts running. That's because you're using the settings to in initialization of a global variable somewhere: those are guaranteed to be initialized before `main` is entered. So don't do that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @KubaOber: Yes, you're absolutely right! :) It's a static variable of that class, similar to global var (but restricted scope).

Comment: All you have to do to avoid that construct is to do what `QCoreApplication` does: maintain a static pointer to the most recently created instance. You then should instantiate the settings engine in `main`, right after you instantiate the application.

Comment: @KubaOber: I'm not at the office anymore (so no source code, no compiler at the moment), so I'm a little bit lost on that. But I'll dig to see what `QCoreApplication` does... Is it kinda singleton or monostate or... ? Sorry if I derailed :)

Comment: It's a singleton, but it's a singleton that's not instantiated behind your back. You have to instantiate it in `main`, or anywhere else, really. And you can then access it via `QCoreApplication::instance()` or the `qApp` macro. You can do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bit strange to see an object with all non-static member functions and all static data members. Are you using it like `SettingsManager()::read(...)`?
It might be more appropriate to just use functions in a namespace, or the singleton pattern.

Anyway, back to the question, you can use [QApplication::applicationDirPath()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) for this purpose. It gets the absolute path to the directory containing the app binary. E.g.

```
QString absPath = QDir(QApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("settings.ini");
```

gets an absolute path to where you want.

## edit: - response to comment about "QApplication doesn't exist error"

it seems like you have an issue with this, since you are using it in a global static initializer, which is run before entering main(), so there is no QApplication yet. You can use a static function variable to delay initialization until the function is called.

You can choose either making a singleton SettingsManager, or just the QSettings (i think that the QSettings is probably weirder as I said above).

Example of QSettings singleton: (needs to be defined in a cpp)

```
QSettings& globalInstance() {
    static QSettings settings(QDir(QApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("settings.ini"));
    return settings;
}
```

if you use that in your functions, it wont create a QSettings until you have called the function, and by then there will be a QApplication instance. But I'd prefer to make the whole class singleton:

**settingsmanager.h**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QSettings>

class SettingsManager
{
public:
    SettingsManager & instance();

    void     write(const QString & key, const QVariant & variant);
    QVariant read (const QString & key) const;

private:
    SettingsManager(const QString & path) : 
        settings(path, QSettings::IniFormat)
    {}

    QSettings settings;
};
```

**settingsmanager.cpp**:

```
#include "settingsmanager.h"

SettingsManager& SettingsManager::instance() {
    static SettingsManager s(QDir(QApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("settings.ini"));
    return s;
}

void SettingsManager::write(const QString & key, const QVariant & variant)
{
    settings.setValue(key, variant);
}

QVariant SettingsManager::read(const QString & key) const
{
    return settings.value(key);
}
```

usage:

```
auto val = SettingsManager::instance().read("key");
```

Comment: I normally try to avoid everything that looks like `ClassName::instance()', like singletons or such flavors, as it doesn't look right to me (some weirdness in C++). I prefer monostate instead, if possible - at least it looks C++. That doesn't mean I don't appreciate your idea/suggestion, on the contrary: thumb/vote up! Thanks man :)

Comment: in that case, I would use `namespace Settings {read(..); write(..); }`, and use an anonymous namespace in the cpp for the global QSettings instance function.

That way, the  interface would be `Settings::read("key")`, looks much cleaner.Or make the instance function outside the class, i.e. settings().read("key");

Comment: I didn't have the build-environment during the week-end. I tried the above code this morning at the office, but it seems it's not 100% correct: I got the following error: `filePath is not a member of QString`... _Something is rotten in Denmark_  :)

Comment: oops... I had in my code `QDir appDir = QApplication::applicationDirPath();` and assumed it would work. Implicit conversions are evil...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the setting path with [`QSettings::setPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#setPath)

So

```
QSettings::setPath(QSettings::IniFormat,QSettings::SystemScope,
                  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

Should do the trick.

Because you have one ini file it seems and not per user base I think `SystemScope` is appropriate here

**Note:** This will set this the location Qt looks for **all** ini files in your program for the `SystemScope` so don't use this if you want multiple ini file location for `SystemScope`

Comment: As a matter of fact there are other 4 INI files used by the app, but located in some different sub-folders (these are used to get the current version of some input data-files). How would you solution/idea affect them, if any? Anyway, thx for sharing your idea. Thumb up! :)

Comment: well this changes the path to where Qt looks for ini files so maybe it will. But you should put your files at one central place anyway I would say. (or one place for system files another for per user config)

Comment: The existing INI files can't be put together. But I guess they still can be accessed explicitly like specifying the path and file name...? I mean without having to interfere somehow with the above `QSetting::setPath`, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that a system wide installed program will likely not have write access to its installation directory.
So you either require that each users installs it on their own or you write the settings to each user's config location, see `QStandardPaths::writableLocation()`
First startup would then copy the installed settings or you could even build the default settings into the application using the Qt resource system

Comment: I tried the above suggestion today, but unfortunately it didn't work...

Comment: @groenhen with "above" you mean the comment or the answer? Btw have you tried relative paths? So set the path to a common one and when opening the file use `foo/bar.ini`? Not sure if this works though.

Comment: "didn't work" is always not really helpful. Did not work in general or with your multiple ini-file locations?

Comment: It didn't work with one single ini file, I don't know exactly why... even after correcting `QSetting` with `QSettings` :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not send ini files with your application. When user launch the application for first time the app will create the ini file. When you read your settings you should always set a default value. For future use user will override the default values and will use the saved settings.

Change your read function with:

```
QVariant SettingsManager::read(const QString & key, const QVariant &defaultValue) const
{
    return settings.value(key,defaultValue);
}
```

and wherever you call the function always provide the default value

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it could prove useful for future development maybe. Thumb up :)